# How do you make such a beautiful generalized Cartesian product?

Tags: math-mode

In one of the books I came across such a beautiful designation of a generalized Cartesian product. I tried to repeat it for a long time and nothing happened.

[image]

Comment: Hello! For future questions please provide the code you already have, so others can work with it.

Comment: You might also have a look at `\bigtimes`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\newcommand{\bigX}{\mathchoice
  {\raisebox{-.33\height}{\scalebox{2.07}{X}}}
  {\raisebox{-.25\height}{\scalebox{1.47}{X}}}
  {\raisebox{-.25\height}{\scalebox{1.03}{X}}}
  {\raisebox{-.25\height}{\scalebox{0.73}{X}}}
}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\X}{\bigX}

\begin{document}

\[
  [a, b) \cap [c, d) = 
    \X_{k = 1}^n \bigl( \max \{a_k, c_k\}, \min \{b_k, d_k\} \bigr)
\]

$
  \displaystyle      \prod \X
  \textstyle         \prod \X
  \scriptstyle       \prod \X
  \scriptscriptstyle \prod \X
$

\end{document}
```

The choice of scaling factors came from trial-and-error to match it up with `\prod`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\X}{\text{\Large{X}}}

\begin{document}
    
    \[ [a,b) \cap [c,d) = \overset{n}{\X_{k=1}} \left (\max\{ a_{k},c_{k}\}, \min\{ b_{k},d_{k}\} \right) \]
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...you could use `\max` and `\min`. How about resizing `X` to look different based on its use in a display, text or script environment?

Comment: Ah yes thanks! It should be the other way around `\text{\Large{X}`. I changed it.

Comment: `\Large` does not take an argument so `\Large X` would be more standard than `\Large{X}` (the `{}` are not an error but do nothing.  `\Large` though is a fixed size and will not adapt to the surrounding math font size.

Answer (score 3):

In plain TeX, we can write:

```
\font\bigrm=\fontname\textfont0 \space scaled2000
\def\X{\mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{\bigrm X}}}}

$$
  [a, b) \cap [c, d) = 
    \X_{k=1}^n \bigl( \max \{a_k, c_k\}, \min \{b_k, d_k\} \bigr)
$$
\bye
```

Answer (score 2):

While it may "look nice", the output shown is fairly obviously an X which may be confusing. Unicode has a codepoint for n-ary product, ⨉ U+2A09 (N-ARY TIMES OPERATOR).

In `unicode-math`, `stix2` and compatible packages this is denoted `\bigtimes`

Unlike answers using X, the font supplies the character at sizes suitable for inline and display without having to do any scaling at the TeX macro level.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}


display
\[
 [a, b) \cap [c, d) = 
    \bigtimes_{k=1}^n \bigl( \max \{a_k, c_k\}, \min \{b_k, d_k\} \bigr)
\]

inline
$ [a, b) \cap [c, d) = 
    \bigtimes_{k=1}^n \bigl( \max \{a_k, c_k\}, \min \{b_k, d_k\} \bigr)$


large
\Large
\[
 [a, b) \cap [c, d) = 
    \bigtimes_{k=1}^n \bigl( \max \{a_k, c_k\}, \min \{b_k, d_k\} \bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```